# AWS SNS Client Initialization results in Construction Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, amazon-ecs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to construct an AWS SNS Client on a server running on ECS, but I keep getting a construction error, specifically "no credentials in the property bag". Here is my initialization code:

```rust
    pub async fn new() -> Result<Self> {
        let data = EcsEnvironmentData::from_this_instance().await?;

        let client = Client::new(&aws_config::load_from_env().await);
        client
            .subscribe()
            .protocol("https")
            .topic_arn(dotenv!("SNS_TOPIC_ARN"))
            .endpoint(format!("https://{}/private/sns", data.networks.first().unwrap().addresses.first().unwrap()))
            .send()
            .await?;

        Ok(Self { client })
    }
```

The endpoint call resolves to something like `https://10.0.148.25/private/sns`, to which I have attached an endpoint on my server. I've attached IAM policies for full access to SNS for the container. I have other AWS SDKs like S3 and SES working fine. Should I be using a different protocol like `http` for this instead of `https`? I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.